# Does noncompact manifold or orbifold have the homotopy type,of CW complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I forget for a while, we don't need the compactness condition here right?

Comment: Relevant comments and references can be found on MO also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36838/are-non-pl-manifolds-cw-complexes even though the question is not exactly the same.

Answer (score 7):

According to *The Topology of CW-Complexes* by Lundell and Weingram
(Van Nostrand Reinhold, 1969) the answer is yes for (separable) manifolds.

Comment: And the proof for smooth manifolds is relatively nice -- on a smooth manifold there is a proper non-negative smooth function $f : M \to \mathbb R$ so $f^{-1}([0,a])$ is a smooth submanifold of $M$ for $a$ a regular value of $f$, and these manifolds exhaust $M$.

Answer (score -2):

For smooth manifolds the following holds.
By the existence of Morse functions one can deduce a handle-body decomposition of a manifold.
This decomposition then yields a CW structure on a space homotopy equivalent to the manifold.
I don't think that compactness is needed in any of the above arguments.

Comment: The Morse function does not give a CW structure on the manifold.  Moreover, the results you're quoting (without reference) do require compactness.

Comment: Let me maybe make this more precise. Any manifold admits a Morse function. Moreover such a morse function induces a handlebody decomposition which in turn induces a CW structure. (collapsing handles to their cocores).  See also http://www.imsc.res.in/~jniyer/handlebody.pdf and Milnor's book on Morse theory.

Comment: The .pdf file you link to does not support your claims, at least not as stated. The CW structure is not on the manifold, there is a homotopy-equivalence to an induced CW-complex.  In particular, the Morse function they use on a non-compact manifold is a *proper* Morse function, meaning the level-sets are compact.  This is not the same thing as a Morse function.

Comment: Yes the argument was to brief. But I still think for smooth manifolds the existence of such a "proper" morse function suffices to see that the manifold has the homotopy type of a CW complex. Of course the CW structure is only given on a space homotopy equivalent to the manifold we started with.